# Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста понять суть ошибки в javafx java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, javafx, websocket

В моём приложении используется WebSocket. Периодически получаю ошибку java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = JavaFX Application Thread

ошибка возникает в методе

```
    private void connectWithDelay() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        if (GLOBAL.waitConnection(AGAIN_CONNECTION_INTERVAL)) {
            connectToServer();
        }
    });
// реализация метода из класса Global 

public boolean waitConnection(int timeWait) {
    WaitConnection wc = new WaitConnection(this, timeWait);
    wc.showAndWait();
    return wc.isTimeout();
}
}

public class WaitConnection extends Stage
```

Что я делаю не так, почему возникает ошибка?

---

забыл добавить стэк

```
    Ошибка: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = JavaFX Application Thread
com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:443)
com.sun.glass.ui.Application.isNestedLoopRunning(Application.java:544)
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.isNestedLoopRunning(QuantumToolkit.java:1139)
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:585)
javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:474)
wcclasses.Global.waitConnection(Global.java:827)
wcclasses.NoticeManager.lambda$connectWithDelay$9(NoticeManager.java:267)
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

```
public boolean waitConnection(int timeWait) {
    WaitConnection wc = new WaitConnection(this, timeWait);
    wc.showAndWait(); // ошибка возникает тут
    return wc.isTimeout();
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы блокируете event тред своей операцией и приложение после этого не может обрабатывать события пользователя (зависает), из чего и бросается исключение

Comment: Понятно. Большое спасибо!